# Why a QgsExpression does not evaluate a feature as expected in PyQGIS 3?

Tags: python, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

When I run following code in QGIS 2.18:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

expression = QgsExpression( u'"area" > 2e8 AND "area" < 3e8' )

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures()
              if expression.evaluate( feat )]

epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 
                           'mem_layer', 
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    mem_layer.addFeature(feat)

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

I got the result of following image:

[image]

However, equivalent code in QGIS 3.x doesn't work.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

expression = QgsExpression( u'"area" > 2e8 AND "area" < 3e8' )

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures()
              if expression.evaluate( feat )]

epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 
                           'mem_layer', 
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    mem_layer.addFeature(feat)

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

Error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in <listcomp>
TypeError: QgsExpression.evaluate(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: too many arguments
  overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsFeature'
```

where it is said that `overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsFeature'`.

So, I did a 'help(QgsExpression.evaluate)' request at Python Console:

```
help(QgsExpression.evaluate)
Help on built-in function evaluate:

evaluate(...)
    Evaluate the feature and return the result.

    .. note::

       this method does not expect that prepare() has been called on this instance

    .. versionadded:: 2.12
    Evaluate the expression against the specified context and return the result.

    :param context: context for evaluating expression

    .. note::

       prepare() should be called before calling this method.

    .. versionadded:: 2.12
```

where it can be observed, at first paragraph, that `Evaluate the feature and return the result` is completely factible and `this method does not expect that prepare() has been called on this instance`.

Searching other possible solutions, I found out this [Joseph's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244068/pyqgis-gives-typeerror-qgsexpression-prepare-argument-1-has-unexpected-type/263660#263660) where it is pointed out that "... you may need to use a combination of the **QgsExpressionContext** and **QgsExpressionContextScope** classes". When I use this approach, in a second run, QGIS 3.0 crashed indefectively.

So, Why a QgsExpression does not evaluate a feature as expected in PyQGIS 3? Is It possible to solve this issue without **QgsExpressionContext** and **QgsExpressionContextScope** classes?

**Editing Note:**

As I am a very big fan of Python List Comprehension, I modified Kadir's lines code to more concise form as:

```
project = QgsProject.instance()

layer = project.mapLayersByName('polygon8')

expression = QgsExpression( '"area" > 2e8 AND "area" < 3e8' )

context = QgsExpressionContext()
scope = QgsExpressionContextScope()
context.appendScope(scope)

eval = [ [scope.setFeature(feat), expression.evaluate(context)][1] for feat in layer[0].getFeatures() ]

feats = [ item[1] for item in enumerate(layer[0].getFeatures()) if eval[item[0]] == 1]

epsg = layer[0].crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 
                           'mem_layer', 
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    mem_layer.addFeature(feat)

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

It works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By changing some lines, your code will work. In [Joseph's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/263660/29431), `context.appendScope(scope)` line have to moved outside the loop to solve crashing issue. [@ndawson's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/296224/29431) explains why.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

expression = QgsExpression( u'"area" > 2e8 AND "area" < 3e8' )

# Added / changed lines ##########
context = QgsExpressionContext()
scope = QgsExpressionContextScope()
context.appendScope(scope)

feats=[]
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    scope.setFeature(feat)
    result = expression.evaluate(context)
    if result:
        feats.append(feat)
################


epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'mem_layer', 'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    feat.setAttributes([i])
    mem_layer.addFeature(feat)

prov.addFeatures(feats)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

Comment: But, I've no idea if it is possible to solve without QgsExpressionContext and QgsExpressionContextScope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it changes a one line solution in pyqgis 2 for a 9 lines solution in pyqgis 3. I don't like it very much but it works.

Comment: I modified your proposal by using two python list comprehension. Please, see my Editing Note. Thanks again.