# How to use comparison and logical operators with filters for a SQL search in Google Earth Engine in a single line

Tags: google-earth-engine

Recently, I [asked](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298864/why-a-qgsexpression-does-not-evaluate-a-feature-as-expected-in-pyqgis-3) how to query by using an expression with comparison and logical operators (u'"area" > 2e8 AND "area" < 3e8') in PyQGIS 3. Searching for an equivalent expression in **Google Earth Engine** (GEE), I found out that it can be done with filters 'gt' and 'lt'. However, for obtaining same result I had to split expression in two parts:

```
// Filter to get "area" > 2e8 AND "area" < 3e8
var selected1 = polygon8.filter(ee.Filter.gt('area', 2e8));
var selected2 = selected1.filter(ee.Filter.lt('area', 3e8));
```

as it can be observed at following code:

```
// Load FeatureCollection

var polygon8 = ee.FeatureCollection("users/joseguerreroa/vector_files/polygon8");

// Center the map on the FeatureCollection.
Map.centerObject(polygon8, 9);

// Filter to get "area" > 2e8 AND "area" < 3e8
var selected1 = polygon8.filter(ee.Filter.gt('area', 2e8));
var selected2 = selected1.filter(ee.Filter.lt('area', 3e8));

// Display the FeatureCollection and print all queried elements.
Map.addLayer(selected2, {color: 'blue'}, 'polygon8');
```

When I use this line in my code:

```
var selected2 = polygon8.filter( ee.Filter.gt('area', 2e8) && ee.Filter.lt('area', 3e8));
```

code works but result is different as expected. So, my question is how to use comparison and logical operators with filters for a SQL search in Google Earth Engine in only a single line.

**Editing note:**

With 'filter', instead 'filterMetadata', it also works:

```
// Load FeatureCollection

var polygon8 = ee.FeatureCollection("users/joseguerreroa/vector_files/polygon8");

// Center the map on the FeatureCollection.
Map.centerObject(polygon8, 9);

// Filter to get "area" > 2e8 AND "area" < 3e8
var selected = polygon8.filter(ee.Filter.gt('area', 2e8)).filter(ee.Filter.lt('area', 3e8));

// Display the FeatureCollection and print all queried elements.
Map.addLayer(selected, {color: 'blue'}, 'polygon8');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot access your feature collection, but assuming that 'area'  is in the metadata of your feature collection, this should work.

```
var selected3 = polygon8.filterMetadata('area', "greater_than", 2e8).filterMetadata('area', "less_than", 3e8);
```